# Spring autowiring not working with proxies

Tags: spring

Here are my spring configuration files and classes:-

I am not able to autowire the proxied class in test Service. After running Test.java I am getting NullPointerException obviously property 'arthmeticCalculator' is not set.

I am not getting whats going wrong? Please help me to solve this problem.

```
<bean id="arthmeticCalculator" class="com.manoj.aop.test.CalculatorImpl"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanNameAutoProxyCreator">
  <property name="beanNames">
        <list>
        <value>*Calculator</value>
        </list>
  </property>
  <property name="interceptorNames">
        <list>
        <value>methodNameAdvisor</value>
        </list>
  </property>
</bean>
<bean id="methodNameAdvisor" class="org.springframework.aop.support.NameMatchMethodPointcutAdvisor">
    <property name="mappedNames">
        <list>
            <value>add</value>
            <value>sub</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="advice" ref="loggingAroundAdvice" />
</bean>
<bean id="loggingAroundAdvice" class="com.manoj.aop.test.LoggingAroundAdvice"/>
<bean id="testService" class="com.manoj.aop.test.TestService">

</bean>
```

Calculator.java:-

```
public interface Calculator {

    public double add(double a,double b);
}
```

CacculatorImpl:-

```
public class CalculatorImpl implements Calculator {

    public double add(double a, double b) {
        return a+b;
    }    
}
```

LoggingAroundAdvice:-

```
public class LoggingAroundAdvice implements MethodInterceptor{


    public Object invoke(MethodInvocation methodInvocation) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("Around Invoice called");
        Object result = methodInvocation.proceed();
        return result;
    }

}
```

TestService:-

```
public class TestService {

    @Autowired
     private Calculator  arthmeticCalculator;


     public void test(){
         System.out.println(arthmeticCalculator.add(5, 10.5));
     }  
}
```

Test.java:-

```
public class Test {    
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("com/manoj/aop/test/aop.xml");
        TestService service = (TestService) context.getBean("testService");
        service.test();
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Does it work without proxies?

Perhaps you need `<context:annotation-config/>`.

Comment: thanks you are correct I forgot annotation-config. Its working now

Answer (score 0):

You haven't included all you configuration. Autowiring is done by the BeanPostProcessor http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.html

You can enable this by `<context:annotation-config/>`.

Comment: by the way is  there any difference between <context:annotation-config/> and <context:component-scan base-package="xxxx" />?

Comment: Yes there is. <context:annotation-config/> instructs Spring framework to do Autowiring, Check @Required and deal with JSR-250 annotations. This does NOT ask to framework to load more beans. On the other hand, <context:component-scan base-package="xxxx" /> instructs the Framework to scan the given package for new spring managed components(@Component, @Repository, @Service, and @Controller). This is usually used when you don't want to configure each of those managed bean in xml.